# How to test my website on PythonAnywhere before setting up my CNAME?

Tags: django, cname, pythonanywhere

I've gotten part way through deploying my new webapp on [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com), and currently it's got the 'Coming Soon' place holder.

When I refresh the app from the web tab it tells me I need to set the CNAME,and from what I remember that involves redirecting from my Domain Service (Gandi in this case).

> There is a problem with your domain name configuration. Take a look at the DNS setup section below for details. Be aware that DNS changes can take some time to propagate across the internet. The exact time they take will depend on your domain configuration, but it could be as long as a day.
>
> You domain's current CNAME is webredir.vip.gandi.net. Check this help page for more information about how to set it up correctly.

**I don't want to do that yet.**

What I want is to 'preview' my page at `webapp-XXXXXX.pythonanywhere.com` before it goes live.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32353579/1075247) suggests that I:

> add a line with the IP address you got from the previous step, then a tab, then the host name you've set up the web app with in PythonAnywhere.

But I've not found that to work, and besides, how would that let me see what's hosted online? It would just let me access it via a different URL.

Here what I added to my *hosts* file:

```
   50.19.109.98    webapp-206115.pythonanywhere.com/
```

**How can I test my website on PythonAnywhere before setting up my CNAME?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access my web app with CNAME](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308397/access-my-web-app-with-cname)

Comment: @rafalmp I've edited to clarify why that didn't help.

Comment: Adding the entry to your hosts file should work. The CNAME tells your browser to use the DNS records for `webapp-XXXXXX.pythonanywhere.com` to get the IP address for `yourdomain.com`. By adding `yourdomain.com` to your hosts file, your browser avoids the DNS lookup and goes straight to the IP. Without actual details (e.g. your hosts file, and the actual values for the domain name and webapp-XXXXXX`), I'm not sure we can help any more.

Comment: Exactly what @Alasdair wrote, additionally - it will cause your browser to send the correct Host: header.

Comment: @Alasdair I've added the line from my hostsfile.

Comment: The entry in your hosts file should be **your** domain, e.g. `50.19.109.98 pureferret.com` (n.b. no trailing slash). Many websites use the same IP 50.19.109.98. PythonAnywhere only knows which website to serve when your browser sends the correct `Host:` header.

Comment: @Alasdair added complication; I have my `gandi.net` redirection set up to go to owner's FB page, so adding `50.19.109.98 pureferret.com` only means typing that in goes to the FB page.

Comment: Adding `50.19.109.98 pureferret.com` to your host file means your browser should go to `50.19.109.98` when you access `pureferret.com`. You shouldn't hit gandi's server at all, so I don't understand why you should be redirected to the fb page.

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here: Alasdair has it exactly right. Putting the line in your hosts file means that Gandhi.net will be ignored when visiting the site from your machine, so the redirect should not happen.

Comment: Ah, one thing -- if your web app is defined as www.pureferret.com on PythonAnywhere rather than just pureferret.com, then you need to include the www in the hosts file too.

Comment: One more thing - after you add the mentioned values to your `hosts` file, the old ones (pointing to FB) can still be cached in your computer's DNS cache, so after editing the `hosts` file reboot your machine, just in case.

Comment: @GilesThomas it work now, thank you for the `www` tip. Sadly it's giving a 500.

Comment: @gilesthomas working now.  It was needing the right host name in the hosts file.  Feel free to answer with that and I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution i found for this is to rename the webapp to `<username>.pythonanywhere.com`. Thats the default for the free subscription and it still works for me after i change to a payed plan. But i dont know if this is because i already had registered a webapp under this name or if this always works.

Comment: Yes, that would always work -- though if your code has any dependencies on the hostname, it might not display exactly as it would if you used the hosts file hack.  And, of course, it doesn't work if you're using the `<username>.pythonanywhere.com` address for another site.